# To create files under existing nested directories in Fedora 23

Tags: linux, files, touch

I can't use `touch` to make files in existing nested directories. I was just wondering if my syntax is off.

```
$ touch dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt
```

Comment: What error message comes back, if any?

Comment: Also, the output of `tree dir1` would be helpful.

Comment: No, your syntax is not off.  Please include the error message you get.

Answer (score 2):

The command `touch` will only create a file, it will not create a nested directory structure as well. For that you can use `mkdir -p` first and then do the `touch` command. You can do them together like this:

```
 $ mkdir -p dir1/dir2/dir3 && touch dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt
```

Keep in mind that this directory structure will be created starting at whatever directory you're located in. To find that out use the `pwd` command.

Comment: Ok thank you for the response! I do have directories already made but i still get that error.

Comment: @JusticeFrye what's the ownership of the directory tree look like? This user can touch files in all the directories down to the last?

Answer (score -1):

Try the following, and compare to what you originally posted.
    `touch /dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt`
lowercase "t" and add the root "/" before your directories. It should work then.

Comment: Thank you the quick feedback! I've tired that but im still getting the "no such file or directory" error

Comment: So the directories already exist as your original post stated, correct? Possibly you are typing something wrong? Does your OS support TAB auto-complete? Try that while typing the directories if so.